# WireShark Version 1.6.7 Uninstallation Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: uninstall, wireshark

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit on a Dell XPS-13. I'm trying to remove WireShark version 1.6.7....

I'm not having any luck.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

How did you install wireshark? Probably should have used Software center or Synaptic or `apt`, they can remove it for you.

Or if you downloaded some file yourself and extracted it, then just delete the extracted files, but that can be tricky to find them all & know whether or not any other programs depend on them (probably not in this case), that's why tools like apt are used.